# Can I use "over and above" here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> There is no natural law over and above the positive laws. (self-made)

I saw others using “over and above”. Can I use it this way, meaning that x is higher in rank than y? Or “over and above” only means “apart from…”?
By the way, what does the over in this phrase mean?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different meanings of the two, which are worth considering separately.

> He paid £5 over and above the agreed minimum repayment.

Such uses state an amount to which something is over what is required.

> He gave service over and above the call of duty.

Such use has an implication of particularly strong action. A soldier who does an extra hour's work on a detail would not be spoken of as having acted "over and above", though he or she literally speaking did, because the phrase is associated with particularly notable acts of self-sacrifice.

> The law of God is over and above the law of Man.

Such a statement claims plainly that the rule of God over-rules the rule temporal government, but the emphasis implied by the use of both *over* and *above* suggests that it is not just greater, but so much greater as to be of a different order.

Note that in the last two cases are as much a matter of nuance than of strict meaning. Stricly anything that is greater or beyond another thing can be called "over and above", but the phrase *implies* that it is *much* greater, except in those cases where we can quantify the difference (as in the first case).